# string.match is too broad, is there any other alternatives that would work better?

Tags: lua, scripting

Currently I am getting passed a bunch of strings from a home automation controller to our driver which I am currently developing.
I receive messages such as `ZAA` and other code which may be `AA` but the `string.match` sometimes will match the `AA` with the `ZAA` if statement.

This issue is much more wide spread than just those two strings (probably around to 10-15 other similarities).
I understand that I could add more conditions to the `if/elseif` statements but surely there is an **exact** match version?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Example; **Even though the string is "AA" it will match "ZAA"**

```
stringInput = "AA"

if string.match("ZAA", stringInput) then
    print("I matched: ZAA")
elseif string.match("AA", stringInput) then 
    print("I matched: AA")
end
```

Comment: How is ur input exactly looking? If it starts with the pattern so u can simply match with `'^AA'`. Otherwise, could u please add some sample inputs?

Comment: Try inverting the args: `string.match(stringInput,"ZAA")`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an **exact** match, just use `==`.

```lua
if stringInput == 'ZAA' then
    print('I matched: ZAA')
elseif stringInput == 'AA' then
    print('I matched: AA')
end
```

Comment: This is probably my answer, and makes perfect sense... I actually have no idea why I am not using these operators anyway, it was just a copy of a similar driver we wrote for another company. I’ll try this tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Lua 5.3. Reference Manual: string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match)

> **string.match (s, pattern [, init])**
> Looks for the first match of pattern (see §6.4.1) in the string s. If it finds one, then match
> returns the captures from the pattern; otherwise it returns nil. If
> pattern specifies no captures, then the whole match is returned. A
> third, optional numeric argument init specifies where to start the
> search; its default value is 1 and can be negative.

so

```
local inputString = "AA"
string.match("ZAA", inputString)
```

will match because `"AA"` is in `"ZAA"`.

You confused the function arguments `s` and `pattern`.

local inputString = "AA"
inputString:match("ZAA")

will not match because the pattern contains more characters than inputString.

But as

```
local inputString = "ZAA"
```

will both match

`inputString:match("AA")` and `inputString:match("ZAA")` you'll probably have to add more constraints.

Please read the manual!